# Redux Newbie Trying to Make Pure-Data Class That Uses Redux Store

Tags: redux, react-redux

**Basic Problem**

I've got a Redux store with the following data:

```
foo: {
    currentId: 1,
    things: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}),
}
```

I'd like to make a utility method *somewhere* (eg. on a `Foo` singleton object) such that any module in my code can do:

```
import Foo from 'foo';
foo.getCurrentFoo(); // returns foo.thins[foo.currentId];
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out where to put it.

**Failed Attempt**

My initial attempt was to create a `Foo` component singleton:

```
// Foo.js
class FooBase extends React.Component {
    getCurrentFoo() {
        return this.state.foo.things[this.state.foo.currentId];
    }
}
const Foor = connect((state) => state.foo)(FooBase);
export default new FooWrapper();
```

But that doesn't work.  Redux complaieds about the property `store` not existing (when I did `new FooWrapper()`).  That makes sense, because my component isn't inside a `<Provider />`.  However, I just want a stand-alone utility class/object, not something actually in the DOM, which rules out `<Provider/>`.

How can I make a method like the one described above, that actually works, without involving `<Provider />` ... and where do I put it?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you're trying to accomplish here.  If you don't want to build stuff for the DOM, then why even involve React components at all?  If you do want to use React, then what's the problem with wrapping your component in a `<Provider />`?

Comment: A) it's not a visible component, it's just a data class, so I'm not sure where in the DOM I would put `<FooDataComponent />` (it seems wrong to put it anywhere in the DOM, since it doesn't render to anything), B) I've inherited a ... messy codebase, and I have code that isn't in "React land" which needs to use the `getCurrentFoo` method (it's some purely data-processing/AJAX code).  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yeah, this helps.  Do you want to be able to use `getCurrentFoo()` in just React components, or in other modules that don't have anything to do with React?

Comment: The latter ... well both I guess, but I already know how to use `connect` with a `<Provider>` for the React components; what I need help with is using `getCurrentFoo` from non-React components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about the `react-redux` helpers is that they allow you to use `connect()` and `<Provider />` to automatically pass the store to child components via React's [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).  However, that doesn't necessarily mean that you **have** to use these helpers, especially in areas of a codebase that don't use React.

So here lies the problem:  `connect()` and `<Provider />` help us by giving our React components access to a singleton instance of a store, but how can we access this store somewhere where `connect()` and `<Provider />` can't be used?

I think the easiest solution here is to create a singleton class that holds on to the store, so any non-React module can still use the store.

So let's say you're creating your store like this:

**init.js**

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const initialState = {
    currentId: 1,
    things: ['foo', 'bar']
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'SET_CURRENT_ID') {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            currentId: action.id
        });
    }

    return state;
};

const store = createStore(reducer);
```

This store takes an action of type `SET_CURRENT_ID` which simply returns a new state with the `currentId` property changed to whatever was handed to it.  You could then get the current "thing" by doing something like `store.getState().things[store.getState().currentId]`.  So let's create a Singleton class that can hold on to the store and provide a wrapper around this functionality.

**store.js**

```
class Store {
    constructor() {
        this._store = undefined;
    }

    setStore(store) {
        this._store = store;
    }

    getCurrentThing() {
        if (this._store) {
            const {things, currentId} = this._store.getState();

            return things[currentId];
        }
    }

    setCurrentThing(id) {
        if (this._store) {
            const action = {
                type: 'SET_CURRENT_ID',
                id
            };

            this._store.dispatch(action);
        }
    }
}

export let singletonStore = new Store();
```

This class creates an instance the first time it is used, and uses that instance every subsequent time.  So when you originally create your store, simply import this class and call `setStore()`.

**init.js**

```
import {singletonStore} from './store';

singletonStore.setStore(store);
```

Then, every subsequent file where `singletonStore` is used will have the same state.

**test.js**

```
import {singletonStore} from './store';

console.log(singletonStore.getCurrentThing()); // 'bar'

singletonStore.setCurrentThing(0);

console.log(singletonStore.getCurrentThing()); // 'foo'
```

This should work just fine for your need to use your store in modules that don't have the benefit of being passed the store magically with `connect()` and `<Provider />`.

Comment: So basically I just ignore `connect`, expose my store to my wrapper, and then just use the store directly from that point on?  Makes total sense.  I guess all this `connect` and `<Provider>` stuff, plus certain warnings in the Redux docs, were scaring me away from even thinking of using the store that way.

Comment: I would probably stick to using `connect()` and `<Provider />` where you can (in your React components), and use this solution for everything else.  There's no reason they can't share the same store, and `connect()` will trigger your React component's lifecycle methods, which would be a pain to implement yourself.

Comment: This might be too big to answer in comments, but if not: should I be `dispatch`-ing actions instead of doing `store.getState()` directly?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question right, but `dispatch()` and `getState()` are used for two completely different purposes.  `dispatch()` allows you to dispatch an action for your reducers to handle, which will in turn update your state tree.  `dispatch()` is the only way to update the store.  `getState()`, on the other hand, is for getting your state tree.  [The API reference](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html) might help clear up some confusion here.

Comment: I did get the core "`dispatch` for write, `getState` for read" idea, but then I saw examples (which I probably misinterpreted) that looked like they were `dispatch`-ing certain actions to get results back.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You may have been looking at examples that demonstrate how to use Redux with React (most Redux examples probably use React in some way).  Because of the way `react-redux` works, there's rarely a need to use `store.getState()` at all, because components that are connected to the store will receive new props as a result of the store updating due to an action being dispatched.  Does this sound familiar?

Comment: Yup :)  Thanks again.